# How can we find the illustrative example in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: functional-analysis

This problem taken from  *Functional Analysis*, by Kreyszig.

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $M\subset H$ a convex subset, and $(x_n)$ a sequence
in $M$ such that $\|x_n\|\rightarrow d,$ where $d =\inf_{x\in M}\|x\|.$ Then  $(x_n)$ converges in $H$. Give an illustrative example in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3.$

My attempt : By using this equality:

$$\left\|\frac{x_n - x_m}{2}\right\|^2 + \left\|\frac{x_n + x_m}{2}\right\|^2= \frac12\,\big(\|x_n\|^2 + \|x_m\|^2\big)$$ we can conclude that $(x_n)$ converges  in $H.$

But my confusion is that how  can we find the   illustrative example in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3?$

Comment: What do you mean by $d=\inf||x||$? I think you must mean $\inf_{x\in M}||x||$, but that is just a guess.

Comment: ya u r  right@TonyK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at $\mathbb{R}^2$. Consider the closed disk $D$ of center $(2,2)$ and radius $1$. Then $\inf_{x\in D}\|x\|=1$. If a sequence $(x_n)$ inside $D$ satisfies $\|x_n\|\to1$, it can be readily seen that $(x_n)$ converges to the point $(1,1)$, which is the closest point of this closed disk to the origin $(0,0)$. You can do the same with a square, or, going to $\mathbb{R}^3$, with a sphere, or a cube, or any shape you find fit.